# Excel: Making different rows read only using multiple check box

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first program in VBA.

I have an excel sheet which contains multiple questions and each question has a check box to make it editable or read only.

Here below an example

1. How many cars you own?
2. How many free coupon you have?

So introducing two check boxes, using that I can make them read only or editable.

So I have tried a vba code to do the same(by Googling). Here below is the code snippet.

```
Private Sub CheckBox13_Click()
    If Sheet3.CheckBox13.Value = False Then
        Sheet3.Range("B20:CZ20").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
        Range("B20:CZ20").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=False
        Range("B20:CZ20").Locked = False
        Sheet3.Range("B20:CZ20").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox14_Click() 'eigth question Hide check box code
    If Sheet3.CheckBox14.Value = False Then
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
        Range("B21:CZ21").Locked = True
        ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=False
        Range("B21:CZ21").Locked = False
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is:

1. Default both rows are editable and both check boxes unchecked
2. Now I check the first check box, so first row color changed and
   became read only.
3. Now I check the second check box. Getting an error.

> error 1004, Application defined or object defined error.

Let me know if I missed out any basic information in order to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know where the problem happen, I would try this :

```
Private Sub CheckBox13_Click()
    If Sheet3.CheckBox13.Value = False Then
        Sheet3.Protect Contents:=False
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Locked = False
        Sheet3.Range("B20:CZ20").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
        Sheet3.Range("B20:CZ20").Locked = True
        Sheet3.Protect Contents:=True
    Else
        Sheet3.Protect Contents:=False
        Sheet3.Range("B20:CZ20").Locked = False
        Sheet3.Range("B20:CZ20").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox14_Click()
    If Sheet3.CheckBox14.Value = False Then
        Sheet3.Protect Contents:=False
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Locked = False
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Locked = True
        Sheet3.Protect Contents:=True
    Else
        Sheet3.Protect Contents:=False
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Locked = False
        Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Details :

1. I've added `Sheet3` before your ranges, (and replaced ActiveSheet by Sheet3) to be sur you're not modifying another Sheet.
2. I've added `ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=False - Sheet3.Range("B21:CZ21").Locked = False` before modifying Range colors to be sure that the Range is not protected.